# Custom framework design guide for .NET (c#)

Tags: c#, .net, xml, architecture

Is it a better idea to create, and are there any available custom frameworks (free) that are build on .NET framework for large scale projects.

I have a project to automate the process of document handling (form filling) of an large organization. What i have to do is to create a set of form structures with different layouts.(around 150 formats). There are some additional options like commenting, approvals and some other things that may apply with some layouts.
The form structures may change in time to time. (optional req.)
Should be able to add more structures later on.

What i am planning to do is to create separate XML files for each layout. And build some sort of a framework (using c# .net) which is able to construct forms with XML data. And when the users fill out the forms, the data will stored in a DB for reconstruct the form and print-documents.

This question may not a point specific one. But i need to find out a better solution.(A better approach)

Comment: Looks like you need a CMS.

Comment: Yes some sort of CMS. but its not just plain forms. It has some logical operations like custom auto completes, advanced filtering and validation, some mathematical calculations and so on.

Do you know any C# base CMS (FREE or commercial)

Comment: This is not a couple of clicks, but I know that projects with similar description had been made on Umbraco and Orchard. It actually requires a lot of work.